# How to disable GPIO event for certain time period after it runs in Python?

Tags: gpio, python

I am creating an event whenever my Raspberry Pi's GPIO pin has a falling edge. However, I want to disable this event for a certain amount of time (5 seconds for example) after each time it runs. I want the event to be enabled again after that time period.

My first thought was just to use sleep(5) within the actual event function. But I believe this will not work due to the event being ran in a separate thread.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to what I am trying to accomplish? This is not as straightforward as I imagined it would be.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                   
import time
from time import sleep

# wait 1 second at startup
sleep(1)

# event function
def event(ev=None):
        print("Event was triggered! Should not run again for 5 seconds.")
        # sleep(5)

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# setup the pin and the event
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.FALLING, callback=event)



while 1:
        continue
```

Comment: Question: Is disabling the "event" same as disabling the falling edge interrupt?

Comment: @tlfong01 yes, if the interrupt that triggers the event function does not run for the 5 seconds, then gets enabled again, I believe that would work for my purposes.

Comment: Let me give an example to clarify. Suppose (1) the GPIO pin is setup to trigger (call back) an event (function) whenever there is a falling edge on the GPIO pin. (2) You can let the event function to (a) first disable the interrupt, and (b) then process/do the event. If the event is short say fixed, one second, then you can sleep 4 more seconds and enable the interrupt again. There are many variations, eg. during the 4 second sleeping period, you can still record new interrupt, but only start the event at the end of the 4 second period.

Comment: You can use a flow chart or decision table to specify the different possible scenarios. If you don't have any deadline and curious to learn new things, you can try python "multi-threading" or  "multi-processing", with one thread/process doing stupid looping instead of the human error bound scary interrupt thing. Yes, looping is stupid, but if I was a space man, I would refuse to go onboard a space ship with many interrupt software stuff.  I would insist on all software using KISS looping algorithms, otherwise the life insurance guys won't talk to me.

Comment: @tlfong01 I think I understand what you're saying. I'll see if I can look into and research up on some of the things you mentioned.

Comment: (1) I like you comment "what I am trying to accomplish .. not as straightforward as I imagined ". Interrupt is indeed is very error bound. (2) Multi-processing (I don't recommend the older python "Multi-threading" module) is "structured" (sort of structured programming, comparing to the messy/impossible to debug GOTO/nested if/then/else programming discipline) (3) Nested if-then-else is also very error bound. If you can python, you can use "dictionary" data/procedure to do "declarative" style to eliminate if-then-else (not to mention case/switch).

Comment: As I said earlier, you need a very long time to understand and practise things. And of course python concurrent programming is not silver bullet, you need to to grasp the important concepts such as "critical section", "semaphores", "coroutines", interprocess message/data passing pipes/pools/tricks to build up your confidence in debugging. Ah, locking up lunch time! see you later. Cheeres.

Comment: You appear t o be using the wrong tool. Any program which relies on `while 1: continue` is just burning resources. It is unclear what you actually want to do but [gpiozero.Button](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html?highlight=event#button) wait_for_press() would seem more suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest something like the following.

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                   

import time

TIMEOUT=5

ok_time = time.time()

time.sleep(1)

# event function
def event(channel):
   global ok_time
   if time.time() > ok_time:
      ok_time = time.time() + TIMEOUT
      print("Event was triggered! Should not run again for 5 seconds.")

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# setup the pin and the event
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.FALLING, callback=event)

while 1:
   time.sleep(60)
```